# Jasmine Javascript jquery click() with function as parameter does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hello I am testing my code in jquery with Karma jasmine and the following code works correctly:

```
  it("Test click", function(){

   var $element = $('a#buttonID');
   var spy = spyOnEvent($element, 'click');

   $element.click();
   expect(spy).toHaveBeenTriggered();
 });
```

But when I run the following code with a function inside click it doesn't work.

```
  it("Test click", function(){

   var $element = $('a#buttonID');
   var spy = spyOnEvent($element, 'click');

  $element.click(function(){
    console.log("Execute some code here")
  });

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenTriggered();

 });

Test click FAILED
    Expected event click to have been triggered on [object Object]
```

The code inside the click function is not executed. I don't know if it is a timeout or is it asynchronous issue?

Comment: `click()` with a function argument adds a listener, it doesn't trigger a click. Why would you expect click to have been triggered?

Comment: `$element.click()` means : `Trigger the click`. `$element.click(function())` means : `When clicked, execute this function`. jQuery's `click` method has different signatures. You can also use `$element.trigger("click")`.

Comment: In code there is a click function as a parameter and I would like to know if that function within the click was executed.

Comment: Best source of information for how jQuery should work is their website: https://api.jquery.com/click/.  If you want to test if the function has been run, test what happens within the function. For instance, if clicking the function does something like `$('#el').show();`, add a spy on `$('#el').show` and check if it was called when `$element.click()` is run.

Comment: How can't Jasmine run the code inside                                   
  `$element.click(function(){
    console.log("Execute some code here")
  })`